# Proper way to distribute binaries to linux cluster

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cluster, deployment

I recently had a disagreement with my boss over the proper way to distribute executable binaries across compute nodes in a Linux cluster.  All the compute nodes are running the distro and the same version (Ubuntu 14.04 specifically).

The current method is mounting a nfs share on all of the compute nodes from the master node and installing all of the executables (and dependencies) into said directory.  There usually 10-20 different executables and they have upgrades once every six months or so.

I believe that we should be deploying deb packages to the compute nodes but since I am new to clusters I feel I am just spouting rhetoric.

So I am asking for feedback and advice on the "proper" way to deploy and upgrade the binaries to the compute nodes.

Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one "proper" way to do this. If the NFS share is working for you, and you're not put off by the SPOF it likely introduces, then keep using that.

I do generally prefer, though, to use a proper configuration management system (ansible in my case) to distribute and install packages. If the package is available through your distro's repository, then you can use Ansible to install whatever specific version you need. If it's a custom package, you can have Ansible copy that package from your own distribution point to each server and then install it.

The key here, though, is to retain *tight control* over the process, and to be able to do it in a automated, testable, repeatable manner. This is not difficult to do, but it will require you to learn a bit about whatever CM system you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  We are in fact using ansible along with along with custom built packages.  The SPOF does bother me but my boss seems to be less bothered by it.

Answer (score 2):

You want all machines in your cluster to have the same exact binary repository all the time. The method you use to deploy those binaries is not related to clusters.

It's perfectly valid to do deploy binaries manually using NFS. Depending on the scope of your operation, building your own packages and running your own debian repository might even be a bit overkill. That being said, using a package manager would make dependency management and rollbacks easier.

As EEAA pointed out, a configuration management system (chef, puppet, ansible, salt) is the way to go in either case, as it makes it easier to ensure that all servers in are in the exact same state.